# The fastest algorithm for splitting image into footprint and nodata values

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, classification

I have a random satellite image that can be divided into 2 classes:

1) `no data values` (all pixel values are equal and randomly vary from image to image)

2) `footprint` (all pixel values are random)

A sum of all the values of `no data` and `footprint` gives a `bounding box`.

**What is the fastest algorithm for dividing a random satellite image into these 2 classes?**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> Are `no data value`-areas always at the border of the image?

`No data value` could **not** be inside of the `footprint` and it may be absent.

> Are `no data-values` always black?

No, it's value may vary from picture to picture. But always equal each other inside one image.

> Does this `no data value`-color appear within the footprint?

Most of the images are grayscale and may be in 16, 8-bit data formats. But i need general algorithm. Case specific algorithm is not what i want.

**UPDATE 2:**

My current approach is:

1) Take every pixel values that lay on the `bounding box` boarder

2) Take most frequent value and set it as `nodata`

3) Reclassify image into 2 classes with values: NoData value - `nodata class`, 
1 - `footprint class`

4) Convert rasters pixels with value 1 into vector format

For big images it take more than 5 minutes to get vector boarders of footprint.

Comment: Flood fill from each border pixel, find the most common colour value present, and take all pixels of that colour found by the flood fills.

Comment: We need more information: Are 'no data value'-areas always at the border of the image? Are no data-values always 'black'? Does this 'no data value'-color appear within the footprint?

Comment: Can you upload the original image without the markings? Two, better.

Comment: What is **your** idea how this could be done? Share **your** research results.

Comment: @MrSmith42 See update.

Comment: @I.Newton See 2 images here: http://dropmefiles.com/mgMu1 (data will be deleted in 14 days)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way for you would be to multiply the pixel intensities. From the images you uploaded, the no data values are esentially of 0 intensity. Instead of going for complex methods, simply multiply the image intensities by 1000.

I used OpenCV and could segment out the regions in under 4 lines of code.
Here's an example -

[image]
[image]